# EFI Boot via USB Hub and extension cables

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, uefi, efi

I'm not able to EFI boot from USB (3.0) flash drives if they plugged into specific USB periphery.

**My question is: Are there any requirements to USB-hardware which are necessary in order to boot with UEFI ?** If the answer is no: what are possible reasons for this behavior?

I tried to plug the USB into the following things:

1. USB Hub (1)
2. USB extension cable
3. USB Hub connected to extension cable connected to Mainboard
4. Mainboard

The results:

1. Not working. Boot option is present but after selecting it, getting a `exit_boot() failed efi_main() failed` error.
2. Not working. No boot option is provided in boot menu (as the USB is not plugged in).
3. Same as 1.
4. Always working as expected.

Not tested it with USB <3.0 (every device is a USB 3.0 device).

Comment: @John That's incorrect. Storage medium and connection is irrelevant for secure boot, all that matters is if the loader is signed correctly.

Comment: Are you using flash drives, hard drives or SSDs?

Comment: @John Yes - I'm able to boot from every kind of USB drive (as long as their aren't  plugged into an extra cable)

Comment: @gronostaj flash drives.

Comment: Sounds like you should try an extension cable from a different manufacturer.

Comment: @fpmurphy I will try hat and it will probably help. But the question was, are there hardware specification in order to boot uefi via USB.